# How to make a properly controlled and reactive component with JSX in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, jsx

I have an input component that is largely just a presentation wrapper for the actual input field itself. The parent component should have control of the value and validation and the like.

Below is a simple sketch of the code and the two components:

`TextInput.js`

```js
export default {
    name: "TextInput",

    props: {
        value: [String, Number]
    },

    methods: {
        inputted(e) {
            this.$emit('input', e);
        }
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <input 
                value={this.value}
                onInput={(e) => this.inputted(e)}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

`Example.js`

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            depositAmount: ""
        };
    },

    methods: {
        handleInput(newValue) {
            let parts = newValue.match(/^(\d+)?(\.)?(\d{0,6})?$/);
            if (parts !== null) {
                this.depositAmount = parts[0];
            }
        },
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <TextInput
                value={this.depositAmount}
                onInput={(e) => this.handleInput(e.target.value)}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

It would seem to me that the lifecycle here should be roughly the following:

- user enters a string
- `onInput` fires on the base `<input>` tag
- `onInput` fires on `TextInput`
- `handleInput` is called and validates the full string against the regex
- if the new input is valid, `depositAmount` is updated, if not nothing happens
- the `value` prop on `TextInput` is set to `depositAmount`
- the `value` of the base `<input>` tag is set to `value` from `TextInput` (which is `depositAmount`)

[The docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#v-model) make it seem as though this should be the case.

This is all fine and dandy when the input is valid. However, when it is not valid, `depositAmount` does not change **but** the value of the base `<input>` element *does change*.

**How can I make the value of the input 1:1 with the parent's data, even when the input updates but the parent's data doesn't?**

[Working example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-input-issue-j9lqz) As you can see, the `<input>` that is disabled and simply taking the value of the validated and sanitized input via `depositAmount` works properly. But the `<input>` that is being interacted with and typed into ignores its controlled value and simply reflects what the user has entered.

---

#### PSEUDO-SOLUTION

The only way I've found to solve this is to add `this.$forceUpdate()` inside the root event handler

`TextInput.js`

```js
...
methods: {
    inputted(e) {
        this.$emit('input', e);
        this.$forceUpdate();
    }
}
...
```

I say this is a "pseudo" solution because while it does solve the problem and forces the input to always take the value it's being fed from its parent, I'm left unsatisfied as I deplore using `$forceUpdate` when it feels like this should be a situation where "it just works."

So while there is a quick patch, I'm leaving this open as I'd love to hear an actual solution or hear what I'm not grasping here that is necessitating the `$forceUpdate`. Seems like Vue's diffing should notice that the prop is different from the actual value of the `<input>` element even though they should be bound.

Comment: You can `prevent default` the action and keep a field `value` in Example.js. This value is passed as prop to TextInput